# Android connecting two devices for bidirectional communication same as like Xender app

Tags: android, connectivity

I want to understand how xender app works programmatically ?
I want to implement same feature in my app to transfer files and messages without internet connection.
Is their any library which can help me ?

Android 2.3 must be supported to my app.

I research many stack Overflow questions but not helpful.
WiFi p2p, WiFi direct and NsdManager all having limitations to support lower android versions, it not give support to below android 4.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

wifi p2p is what xender uses. But that feature sadly needs android api level 14 or greater. If you want to share files offline anyway on lower api, the only way is to connect the 2 devices on the same local n/w using wifi hotspot or something, once connected you can start the apps and everything should work just like xender.

Comment: Good news is that there are lots of networking permission that allows you to create a customized hotspot on the android device with just a button click, thus setting up hotspot manually and connecting can be avoided.